# Set bar widths using broken_barh with dates in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a Gantt chart but I cannot work out how to define the xwidth part of the broken_barh in the correct data format. The only format I can get to work is the date format but the bar always ends up far too wide and I would rather enter a number of days.

I would like the bar that appears in the below to stretch between 01/09/2021 and 01/10/2021 (British date standard).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
  
fig, gnt = plt.subplots() 
  
# Setting Y-axis limits 
gnt.set_ylim(0, 280) 

# Setting X-axis limits 
datemin = dt.date(2020, 12, 1)
datemax = dt.date(2021, 12, 31)
gnt.set_xlim(datemin, datemax) 
  
gnt.set_xlabel('Date') 
gnt.set_ylabel('Survey') 
  
# Setting ticks on y-axis 
gnt.set_yticks([15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95,105,115,125,135,145,155,165,175,185,195,205,215,225,235,245,255,265]) 

# Labelling tickes of y-axis 
gnt.set_yticklabels(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26'])

  
# Setting graph attribute 
gnt.grid(True) 


gnt.broken_barh([
    (
        date(2021, 9, 1),
        date(2021, 10, 1)
    )],
    (260, 9), facecolors =('tab:orange')) 

fig.set_size_inches(12, 15)
```

The chart I end up with looks like this:
[image]

and clearly the width of the bar, which I want to represent a month, is too wide.

How do I need to format the xWidth portion of the broken_barh function? I want to be able to put in a number of days.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading, I found a pretty messy solution. The duration (xrange) part of the .broken_barh function can be rendered by adding the number of days you require to the smallest start date possible (01/01/01):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
  
fig, gnt = plt.subplots() 
  
# Setting Y-axis limits 
gnt.set_ylim(0, 280) 

# Setting X-axis limits 
datemin = dt.date(2020, 12, 1)
datemax = dt.date(2021, 12, 31)
gnt.set_xlim(datemin, datemax) 
  
gnt.set_xlabel('Date') 
gnt.set_ylabel('Survey') 
  
# Setting ticks on y-axis 
gnt.set_yticks([15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95,105,115,125,135,145,155,165,175,185,195,205,215,225,235,245,255,265]) 

# Labelling tickes of y-axis 
gnt.set_yticklabels(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26'])

  
# Setting graph attribute 
gnt.grid(True) 


gnt.broken_barh([
    (
        date(2021, 9, 1),
        date(1, 1, 1)+timedelta(days=10) #This adds a width of 10 days
    )],
    (260, 9), facecolors =('tab:orange')) 

fig.set_size_inches(12, 15)
```

[image]

Comment: Or just use dt.date.fromordinal(10) in place of:

date(1, 1, 1)+timedelta(days=10)

Comment: For me, the solution was to simply use timedeltas. I.e. `broken_barh([(date1, dt.timedelta(days=10)), (date2, dt.timedelta(days=5))], (10, 9), facecolors='tab:blue')`